# Solve this question involving temperatures?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, problem-solving, applications

So I am given 2 formulas:
$$ \frac{dT}{dt}=-k(T_t-T_s)$$
Where $\frac{dT}{dt}$ rate at which the object's temperature is changing

$T(t)$ is the temperature of the object at time $t$

$T(s)$ is the constant surrounding temperature

$k$ is some real number to be found

$$T(t)-T(s)=[T(0)-T(s)]e^{-kt}$$

Scenario: Suppose that a cup of soup cooled from 90◦C to 60◦C after 10 minutes in a room whose temperature was 20◦C.
How much longer would the soup take to cool to 35◦C

Please show all working so that I may learn. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, we have the following equation $$T(t)-T(s)=(T(0)-T(s))e^{-kt}$$

$\color{red}{\text{Given condition}}$: It takes $t=10\ minutes $ for temperature fall $\color{blue}{90^\circ \ C \to 60^\circ \ C}$

Setting the corresponding values, final temperature $T(t)=60^\circ\ C$ , initial temperature $T(0)=90^\circ\ C$ & surrounding/room temperature $T(s)=20^\circ\ C$  we get    $$60-20=(90-20)e^{-k(10)}$$

$$e^{-10k}=\frac{40}{70}=\frac{4}{7}$$
$$-10k=\ln\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)$$
$$k=-\frac{1}{10}\ln\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)\tag 1$$

Now, for temperature fall $\color{red}{90^\circ \ C \to 35^\circ \ C}$ , setting $T(t)=35^\circ \ C$, $T(0)=90^\circ\ C$ & $T(s)=20^\circ\ C$ we get 
$$35-20=(90-20)e^{-kt}$$
$$e^{-kt}=\frac{15}{70}=\frac{3}{14}$$
$$\implies -kt=\ln\left(\frac{3}{14}\right)$$
Setting the value of $k$ from (1), we get time $t$ as follows
$$t\frac{1}{10}\ln\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{3}{14}\right)$$
$$t=\frac{10\ln\left(\frac{3}{14}\right)}{\ln\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)}\approx 27.53\ minutes$$

Answer (score 0):

I would’ve written this as a comment under Harish Chandra Rajpoot’s answer, but I lack the reputation.

I believe the answer should be $17.53$ minutes because the original problem said “How much longer” and 10 minutes have already passed from the soup going from 90°C to 60°C.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/2086434)